# Xcode project is damaged and cannot be opened due to a parse error

Tags: ios, xcode

When I run my project on my local machine it compiles, runs, exports perfectly. So I do not face any issues. But when I push it to CI(CircleCI) and build there, my build gets failed and I get the next quite strange errors:

```
xcodebuild Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 
"No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Error: Error Domain=Xcode3ProjectErrorDomain Code=2 
"The project ‘MyProj’ is damaged and cannot be opened due to a parse error. 
Examine the project file for invalid edits or unresolved source control conflicts.
```

But the thing is it is running on my local machine without any issues. Also I want to mention that the proj file is COMPLETELY compilable and no Git-merge issues there.

Any idea why I might face this issue and how it can be fixed? If you have any questions please let me know.

Also I noticed that Fastlane builds .xcodeproj instead of .xcworkspace.

For the build command I use this:

```
bundle exec fastlane gym 
--workspace "MyProj.xcworkspace" 
--scheme MyProj 
--archive_path $ARCHIVE_PATH 
--output_directory $OUTPUT_FOLDER
```

but I get this error:

```
Unable to open project file '/MyProj.xcodeproj' in workspace 'MyProj.xcworkspace'.
```

So somehow it tries to open .xcodeproj instead of .xcworkspace. But I do not understand why? Is there anything what I do wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Look at an .xcworkspace with a text editor and you’ll see it’s just a list of projects so I don’t think the fastlane invocation is a problem. Does CircleCI have a setting to checkout clean vs a quicker merge type checkout?

Comment: @WarrenBurton thanks for your reply! No, it does not have it =/ so you think it's a merge policy issue?

Comment: @WarrenBurton but I'm just building the branch with clean .xcodeproj file. I mean there is no Git marks in it and the project is compiling perfectly

Comment: I’d look at the logging/setup for CI and try and figure out how it checks out the branch. It feels like CI is checking out the branch and leaving merge marks in the project file.